# How to manage more effectively html button click events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

It looks ridiculous to do so many tasks on a button click while every button should have its own events:

```
 function allStories() {
     $('#zero-md').hide();
     $('.container-aboutme').hide();
     $('.container-allstories').show();
     $('.container-allstories').load("pages/allstories.html");
     $("#home").removeClass("nav-link active").addClass("nav-link");
     $("#aboutme").removeClass("nav-link active").addClass("nav-link");
     $("#allposts").removeClass("nav-link").addClass("nav-link active");
 }

 function aboutMe() {
     $('#zero-md').hide();
     $('.container-allstories').hide();
     $('.container-aboutme').show();
     $('.container-aboutme').load("pages/about.html");
     $("#home").removeClass("nav-link active").addClass("nav-link");
     $("#allposts").removeClass("nav-link active").addClass("nav-link");
     $("#aboutme").removeClass("nav-link").addClass("nav-link active");
 }

     <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link" id="allposts" onclick="allStories()" href="#">All posts</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link" id="aboutme" onclick="aboutMe()" href="#">About me</a>
     </li>
```

Is there is a better, more effective way to organize such events with less code?

Comment: What is the problem you're facing? Could you elaborate? What do mean by _every button should have its own events_?

Comment: This looks straight-forward to combine to a single function with a parameter.  What problem are you facing? (as asked above).  As you code appears to work, you might like to ask on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean this

```js
$("#nav").on("click",".nav-link",function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // stop the link
  const id = this.id;
  const $thisContainer = $('.container'+id);

  $('#zero-md').hide();
  $('.container').hide(); // hide all containers
  $thisContainer.load("pages/"+id+".html",function() { // perhaps not load if already loaded
    $thisContainer.fadeIn("slow");
  }) ;
  $(".nav-link").removeClass("active")
  $(this).addClass("active")
})
```

```html
<ul id="nav">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="allposts" href="#">All posts</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="about" href="#">About me</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Try to keep your code DRY (don't repeat yourself.)

Add an event listener in your JS.
Use `e.target` to determine what was clicked.
Chain your commands together when they're operating on the same elements.
Don't remove a class and then add the same class back.  Just remove the one you want to get rid of.

I've added some stand in elements since not everything was present in your HTML.

```js
$('.nav-link').click( (e)=>{
  let theLink = $(e.target).attr('id');
  const container = '.container-'+$(theLink).attr('id');
  $('#zero-md').hide();
  $('.container').hide();
  $(container).show().load("pages/"+theLink+".html");
  alert('loading: pages/'+theLink+'.html');
  $("#home").removeClass("nav-link active").addClass("nav-link");
  $(".nav-link").removeClass("active");
  $("#"+theLink).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.active {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link" id="allstories" href="#">All posts</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link" id="aboutme" href="#">About me</a>
</li>
<div class="container container-allstories">All Stories</div>
<div class="container container-aboutme">About Me</div>
<div id="zero-md">Zero MD</div>
```